# Ideal ways for Choosing DataSet or DataTable

Tags: c#, performance, .net-datatable

1. Required to know the performance overhead associated with DataSet
   and DataTable.
2. When it comes choosing which data structure might be good and performance oriented

   - what if single Result Set is returned from Stored Procedure
   - what if more than one Result Set is returned from Stored Procedure

Question may arise choosing whether which one should we need to go for?

Here is the coding snippet from Business Access Layer:

```
// Method 1: Using DataTable
public static ArrayList GetProctorsDetails(LoginUser sessionDetails)
{
    List<ProctorUserDetails> proctorUserDetailsList = new List<ProctorUserDetails>();
    DataTable dsProctorUserDetails = PasswordGeneratorDAL.GetProctorsDetails(sessionDetails);
    
    if (dtProctorUserDetails != null && dtProctorUserDetails.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dtProctorUserDetails.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            ProctorUserDetails proctorUserDetails = new ProctorUserDetails();
            if (dtProctorUserDetails.Rows[i].Table.Columns.Contains("UserID") && dtProctorUserDetails.Rows[i]["UserID"] != DBNull.Value)
                proctorUserDetails.UserID = Convert.ToString(dtProctorUserDetails.Rows[i]["UserID"]);
            if (dtProctorUserDetails.Rows[i].Table.Columns.Contains("LoginName") && dtProctorUserDetails.Rows[i]["LoginName"] != DBNull.Value)
                proctorUserDetails.LoginName = Convert.ToString(dtProctorUserDetails.Rows[i]["LoginName"]);
            if (dtProctorUserDetails.Rows[i].Table.Columns.Contains("FirstName") && dtProctorUserDetails.Rows[i]["FirstName"] != DBNull.Value)
                proctorUserDetails.FirstName = Convert.ToString(dtProctorUserDetails.Rows[i]["FirstName"]);
            if (dtProctorUserDetails.Rows[i].Table.Columns.Contains("LastName") && dtProctorUserDetails.Rows[i]["LastName"] != DBNull.Value)
                proctorUserDetails.LastName = Convert.ToString(dtProctorUserDetails.Rows[i]["LastName"]);
    
            proctorUserDetailsList.Add(proctorUserDetails);
        }
    }
    return proctorUserDetailsList;
}
```

---

```
// Method 2: Using DataSet
public static ArrayList GetProctorsDetails(LoginUser sessionDetails)
{
    List<ProctorUserDetails> proctorUserDetailsList = new List<ProctorUserDetails>();
    DataSet dsProctorUserDetails = PasswordGeneratorDAL.GetProctorsDetails(sessionDetails);
    
    if (dsProctorUserDetails != null && dsProctorUserDetails.Tables.Count > 0 && dsProctorUserDetails.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dsProctorUserDetails.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            ProctorUserDetails proctorUserDetails = new ProctorUserDetails();
            if (dsProctorUserDetails.Tables[0].Columns.Contains("UserID") && dsProctorUserDetails.Tables[0].Rows[i]["UserID"] != DBNull.Value)
                proctorUserDetails.UserID = AESCrypto.Encrypt(Convert.ToString(dsProctorUserDetails.Tables[0].Rows[i]["UserID"]));
            if (dsProctorUserDetails.Tables[0].Columns.Contains("LoginName") && dsProctorUserDetails.Tables[0].Rows[i]["LoginName"] != DBNull.Value)
                proctorUserDetails.LoginName = Convert.ToString(dsProctorUserDetails.Tables[0].Rows[i]["LoginName"]);
            if (dsProctorUserDetails.Tables[0].Columns.Contains("FirstName") && dsProctorUserDetails.Tables[0].Rows[i]["FirstName"] != DBNull.Value)
                proctorUserDetails.FirstName = Convert.ToString(dsProctorUserDetails.Tables[0].Rows[i]["FirstName"]);
            if (dsProctorUserDetails.Tables[0].Columns.Contains("LastName") && dsProctorUserDetails.Tables[0].Rows[i]["LastName"] != DBNull.Value)
                proctorUserDetails.LastName = Convert.ToString(dsProctorUserDetails.Tables[0].Rows[i]["LastName"]);
    
            proctorUserDetailsList.Add(proctorUserDetails);
        }
    }
    return proctorUserDetailsList;
}
```

---

```
// To call SP to whichever prototype/return type
public static <String/DataSet/DataTable> GetProctorsDetails(LoginUser sessionDetails)
{
    List<object> parameter = new List<object>();
    parameter.Add(SqlHelper.BuildSqlParameter("OrganizationID", SqlDbType.BigInt, sizeof(Int64), sessionDetails.OrganizationID));
    parameters.Add(SqlHelper.BuildSqlParameter("Status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 5, "Status", string.Empty, ParameterDirection.Output));
    
    using (DataTable dt = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataTable(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "UspGetUserOrgDetails", parameters.ToArray(), false))
    {
        statusCode = Convert.ToString(SqlHelper.GetParameterValue(parameters[1]));
    }
    
    using (DataSet ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "UspGetUserOrgDetails", parameters.ToArray(), false))
    {
        statusCode = Convert.ToString(SqlHelper.GetParameterValue(parameters[1]));
    }
    return <statusCode/ds/dt>;
}
```

How should be our choice of selection? Especially for .NET Framework or Core or some other programming language

Comment: `DataSet` is a collection of `DataTable`. Whenever you need to process multiple different `DataTable`s for one database, you can use `DataSet` to take advantage of its capabilities like `DataRelation`, Data Integrity and Data Serialization. But if you just need only work on one table to process its data (like using `DataRow`) then DataTable would be enough.

Comment: I assume that the `DataSet` example should be returning `dsProctorUserDetails` not an `ArrayList`? For that matter neither of your example methods is actually returning a value at all. Can you please fix these examples so that they should compile.

Comment: Updated the semantic syntax!... The above shown was a partial coding snippets. There were other packages inherited to this class with `try`, `catch`, `finally`. As it would grow huge.. @ChrisSchaller

Comment: I appreciate that but it is important that you write a complete snippet if you want a code review, otherwise the first response in the review is that the code does not compile... If you are not going to include the return statement, don't include the method prototype.

Comment: From these two examples, there is only negligible performance losses in dataset, your question should actually be about the _implementation_ or _definition_ of `GetProctorsDetails`

Comment: Don't write your own ORM, use Dapper -- https://dapper-tutorial.net/ .

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question after receiving answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out by @iSR5's comment, A `DataSet` is basically a wrapper around a *collection* or `DataTable` objects. It has some other helpful utility methods, but from a performance point of view the only performance issue with your logic is that in the `DataSet` solution you need to access the table to read from through the indexer that has *assumed* that there is a table at index `0`.

- **So there is not really a performance argument to choose one over the other.**
- Given that both solutions for your *Business layer* `GetProctorsDetails` do not return either of the `DataSet` or `DataTable` objects, your ***ONLY*** consideration is actually the implementation of `PasswordGeneratorDAL.GetProctorsDetails(sessionDetails);`

  - Your code examples already demonstrate that you can manage both types of results from this method.

#### Focusing on the DAL Implementation

> Specifically for `SqlHelper` there is no measurable difference between `ExecuteDataTable` and `ExecuteDataSet`, in fact if you have a look at the source code, most implementations or `ExecuteDataTable` use a `DataSet` internally:
>
> ```
> var ds = new DataSet();
> using (var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
> {
>     dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
> }
> return ds.Tables[0];
> ```
>
> > **DO NOT** make the assumption that using `DataSet` is therefore more performant!

The *only* reason you should consider a `DataSet` over a `DataTable` is because you want to return multiple tables of records. If you are only going to return a single table of results, `DataTable` is the better choice because it simplifies the code, but also conveys the correct expectation to callers that there is only a single table of records in this result set.

#### Back to the Business layer mapping

The *code smell* to watch out for is when you have lots of code that is accessing an item in an array at index zero, in your second code example the following indexer is evaluated 5 times for every record:

```
dsProctorUserDetails.Tables[0]
```

It's not a big deal at runtime, but the use of `DataSet` in this scenario has added an unnecessary level of complexity and uncertainty into this code.

If we refactor your 1st two examples to reduce the repetitive column validations, (do you really expect or want to support the condition of only some if these columns being present in the result set?) you will see there is even less difference in the usage between `DataTable` and `DataSet`:

```
// Method 1: Using DataTable
public static ArrayList GetProctorsDetails(LoginUser sessionDetails)
{
    List<ProctorUserDetails> proctorUserDetailsList = new List<ProctorUserDetails>();
    DataTable dtProctorUserDetails = PasswordGeneratorDAL.GetProctorsDetails(sessionDetails);

    if (dtProctorUserDetails != null && dtProctorUserDetails.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        var userIdOrd = dtProctorUserDetails.Columns.Contains("UserID") ? dtProctorUserDetails.Columns["UserID"].Ordinal : -1;
        var loginOrd = dtProctorUserDetails.Columns.Contains("LoginName") ? dtProctorUserDetails.Columns["LoginName"].Ordinal : -1;
        var firstNameOrd = dtProctorUserDetails.Columns.Contains("FirstName") ? dtProctorUserDetails.Columns["FirstName"].Ordinal : -1;
        var lastNameOrd = dtProctorUserDetails.Columns.Contains("LastName") ? dtProctorUserDetails.Columns["LastName"].Ordinal : -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < dtProctorUserDetails.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var row = dtProctorUserDetails.Rows[i];
            ProctorUserDetails proctorUserDetails = new ProctorUserDetails();
            if (userIdOrd > 0 && !row.IsNull(userIdOrd))
                proctorUserDetails.UserID = AESCrypto.Encrypt(Convert.ToString(row[userIdOrd]));
            if (loginOrd > 0 && !row.IsNull(loginOrd))
                proctorUserDetails.LoginName = Convert.ToString(row[loginOrd]);
            if (firstNameOrd > 0 && !row.IsNull(firstNameOrd))
                proctorUserDetails.FirstName = Convert.ToString(row[firstNameOrd]);
            if (lastNameOrd > 0 && !row.IsNull(lastNameOrd))
                proctorUserDetails.LastName = Convert.ToString(row[lastNameOrd]);

            proctorUserDetailsList.Add(proctorUserDetails);
        }
    }
    return proctorUserDetailsList;
}
```

For performance reasons, I have moved the column exists check out of the row indexer (all rows in the table will have the same columns), by storing and using the column *ordinal* we can squeeze out some additional CPU ticks by not having to compare strings.

See if you can spot the main difference between Method 1 and Method 2:

```
// Method 2: Using DataSet
public static ArrayList GetProctorsDetails(LoginUser sessionDetails)
{
    List<ProctorUserDetails> proctorUserDetailsList = new List<ProctorUserDetails>();
    DataSet dsProctorUserDetails = PasswordGeneratorDAL.GetProctorsDetails(sessionDetails);
    if (dsProctorUserDetails != null && dsProctorUserDetails.Tables.Count > 0 && dsProctorUserDetails.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        DataTable dtProctorUserDetails = dsProctorUserDetails.Tables[0];

        var userIdOrd = dtProctorUserDetails.Columns.Contains("UserID") ? dtProctorUserDetails.Columns["UserID"].Ordinal : -1;
        var loginOrd = dtProctorUserDetails.Columns.Contains("LoginName") ? dtProctorUserDetails.Columns["LoginName"].Ordinal : -1;
        var firstNameOrd = dtProctorUserDetails.Columns.Contains("FirstName") ? dtProctorUserDetails.Columns["FirstName"].Ordinal : -1;
        var lastNameOrd = dtProctorUserDetails.Columns.Contains("LastName") ? dtProctorUserDetails.Columns["LastName"].Ordinal : -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < dtProctorUserDetails.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var row = dtProctorUserDetails.Rows[i];
            ProctorUserDetails proctorUserDetails = new ProctorUserDetails();
            if (userIdOrd > 0 && !row.IsNull(userIdOrd))
                proctorUserDetails.UserID = AESCrypto.Encrypt(Convert.ToString(row[userIdOrd]));
            if (loginOrd > 0 && !row.IsNull(loginOrd))
                proctorUserDetails.LoginName = Convert.ToString(row[loginOrd]);
            if (firstNameOrd > 0 && !row.IsNull(firstNameOrd))
                proctorUserDetails.FirstName = Convert.ToString(row[firstNameOrd]);
            if (lastNameOrd > 0 && !row.IsNull(lastNameOrd))
                proctorUserDetails.LastName = Convert.ToString(row[lastNameOrd]);

            proctorUserDetailsList.Add(proctorUserDetails);
        }
    }
    return proctorUserDetailsList;
}
```

If you missed it, in the second example we get the table at index 0 from the dataset, from then on the processing is identical:

```
DataSet dsProctorUserDetails = PasswordGeneratorDAL.GetProctorsDetails(sessionDetails);
DataTable dtProctorUserDetails = dsProctorUserDetails.Tables[0];
```

Remember my point above:

> DO NOT make the assumption that using DataSet is therefore more performant!

There is *zero* net difference between 1 and 2 in the refactored versions, in 1 the `.Tables[0]` is executed once inside the `SqlHelper` routine, in 2 it is executed in our code.

---

#### Additional Considerations

In General, using the DataTable solution is likely to have less long term maintenance issues *especially* when you want to support a stored procedure that might return multiple tables of result sets.

- When there are multiple tables in the response, only the calling context (the context that provides the SQL) is likely to know *which* one of the tables in the result set is the table that this method needs to interact with, unless you can *guarantee* that the proctor details table that you want to inspect is always the first table in the `DataSet`.

  - So `DataTable` is better than trying to blindly support `DataSet`, to properly support `DataSet` you should be iterating the *Tables* within it to identify which table matches the columns that you are expecting to read from.

> How should be our choice of selection? Especially for .NET Framework or Core or some other programming languge

From a performance and maintenance perspective I would not advocate using `DataTable` *or* `DataSet` in a new project or any .Net Core projects moving forward. Instead I would recommend moving towards a typed data access layer using an ORM framework or tool (Entity Framework/nHibernate). To keep your DAL and DTO classes decoupled you can use *Interfaces* instead of *DataSets/DataTables*. There are also tools like *AutoMapper* that replace your first two code examples to map between your DAL and business layer or DTOs.

In legacy or simple .Net FX applications `DataSet` or `DataTable` can work, even moving forward, however there have been other significant advances in the IDE *tooling* and syntax and language runtimes that mean it is often easier and less error prone to work in *typed* data models, so avoiding `DataTable` and `DataSet` altogether.

The issue with DataTable and DataSets, from a performance perspective, is that code like this must search for and pre-validate every property on demand. When you move to a *typed*  interface the property resolution and type validation is performed in an efficient manner when the data is loaded from the database, or when it is deserialized.

- Note, as you flagged performance as a driving factor, implementing an ORM and or a DTO mapper like *AutoMapper* itself is not likely to be more performant, in fact it can be perceived to be slower in some cases, especially for loading data records, however your code becomes more reliable saving you development time and they can award you performance and maintenance gains throughout the rest of your application to offset or trade off any losses you might be able to measure at data load.

Comment: If the latest edits have invalidated (part of) your answer, please notify me and we'll rollback the edits on the question. We take answer invalidation seriously here.

Comment: thanks @Mast the edits don't really change a lot, just confirmed what I thought was going on, I'll tldr my answer i guess